# Roxygen2 not finding all exported S3 methods but complains @S3method is depricated

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

I have some R code with S3 classes, some of the methods are able to handle multiple classes. I am trying to hide that detail from the upstream class users. A simplified example looks like this (with classes 2p, 3p, 3m):

```
#' @export
foo <- function(myclass){
  UseMethod("foo", myclass)
}

#' @export
foo.2p <- function(myclass){
  return(myclass+2)
}

#' @export
foo.3p <- function(myclass){
  return(myclass+3)
}

#' @export
foo.3m <- function(myclass){
  return(myclass*3)
}

#' @export
bar <- function(myclass){
  UseMethod("bar", myclass)
}

#' @export
bar.2p <- function(myclass){
  return(2)
}

#' @export bar.3m
#' @export
bar.3p <- bar.3m <- function(myclass){
  return(3)
}
```

My problem is, roxygen2 is not correctly identifying bar.3m as an S3 method. If I explicitly say @S3method bar.3m roxygen2 warns me that "@S3method is deprecated. Please use @export instead." How do I make roxygen2 understand bar.3m is an S3 method? Note: the real functions are not trivial.

Comment: What happens if you define `bar.3p` and `bar.3m` separately?

Comment: That does work. (e.g. bar.3m <- function(){}; bar.3p <- bar.3m) but it makes my code not as pretty as it was.